# parse html string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to extract part of html string which format is given as below. This html string is returned by `var contents = $("#content").html()`

```
blah1 blah1
<p> blah2 blah2 </p>
```

Then I use

```
start = contents.indexOf("<p>");
end = contents.indexOf("</p>");
```

to get the start and end positions. So I can use contents.slice(start, end) to extract the string I want.

But in IE browser the `<p>` tag is capital `<P>` and in Chrome and Firefox, they user `<p>`

How can I include both cases so that my JavaScript function can work in all browsers? Thanks

Comment: don't use string operations when you're already using jquery... `$('#content p').text()` will retrieve everything inside the P for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('#content p').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just grab the innerHTML of the p tag in question?

jQuery:

```
var contents = $("#content > p").html();
```

or even, just the plain text:

```
var contents = $("#content > p").text();
```